# Image With buttons inside

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a listview with images and i need to have buttons inside the images and a label below the image, I tried with relative and absolute layouts , but dont understand how to do it.
Have some code alredy done, but the buttons do not stay in the centered in relation with the image and before image is loaded the background stays blue.

here is a example:

[image]

What have done so far:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Code:

```
<Grid Padding="0">
        <ListView x:Name="CoversListview" SeparatorVisibility="None" ItemsSource="{Binding Covers}" HasUnevenRows="True">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <!--left, top, right, bottom-->
                    <ViewCell>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="0"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <AbsoluteLayout  x:Name="ViewLayout" BindingContext="{Binding Item1}"  Padding="10,10,0,0" >
                                <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" BackgroundColor="#01426A">
                                    <ffimageloading:CachedImage x:Name="CoverShow" Source="test.jpg" LoadingPriority="Highest" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" WidthRequest="160" HeightRequest="234" Aspect="AspectFill">
                                        <ffimageloading:CachedImage.GestureRecognizers>
                                            <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_OnTapped">
                                            </TapGestureRecognizer>
                                        </ffimageloading:CachedImage.GestureRecognizers>
                                    </ffimageloading:CachedImage>
                                    <Label Text="Cover Name" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" FontSize="16" LineBreakMode="NoWrap" TextColor="White" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                                </StackLayout>
                                <AbsoluteLayout x:Name="ViewControls" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="1,1,1,1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All">
                                    <StackLayout  Orientation="Vertical" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="1,1,1,1">
                                        <Grid>
                                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="110" />
                                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                <RowDefinition Height="36" />
                                                <RowDefinition Height="36" />
                                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <customRenders:MyButton x:Name="ShowButtonFrame"  BackgroundColor="#C8DBEF" TextColor="#01426A" ConfigurationItem ="{Binding .}"  Grid.Row="1" Text="Show"  CornerRadius="16" FontSize="12" BorderWidth="0" Clicked="Button_OnClicked_ShowItem1"/>
                                            <customRenders:MyButton x:Name="DownButtonFrame"  BackgroundColor="#C8DBEF" TextColor="#01426A" ConfigurationItem ="{Binding .}"  Grid.Row="0"  Text="Download"  CornerRadius="16" FontSize="12"  BorderWidth="0" Clicked="Button_OnClicked_DownItem1"/>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </StackLayout>
                                </AbsoluteLayout>
                            </AbsoluteLayout>

                            <AbsoluteLayout  x:Name="FrameItem" Grid.Column="2" IsVisible="{Binding IsVisible}" BindingContext="{Binding Item2}" Padding="0,10,0,0"  >
                                <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" BackgroundColor="#01426A">
                                    <ffimageloading:CachedImage x:Name="CoverShow2" Source="test.jpg" LoadingPriority="Highest" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" WidthRequest="160" HeightRequest="234" Aspect="AspectFill">
                                        <ffimageloading:CachedImage.GestureRecognizers>
                                            <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_OnTapped">
                                            </TapGestureRecognizer>
                                        </ffimageloading:CachedImage.GestureRecognizers>
                                    </ffimageloading:CachedImage>
                                    <Label Text="Cover Name" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" FontSize="16" LineBreakMode="NoWrap" TextColor="White" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                                </StackLayout>
                                <AbsoluteLayout x:Name="ViewControls2" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="1,1,1,1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All">
                                    <StackLayout  Orientation="Vertical" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="1,1,1,1">
                                        <Grid>
                                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="110" />
                                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                <RowDefinition Height="36" />
                                                <RowDefinition Height="36" />
                                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <customRenders:MyButton x:Name="ShowButtonFrame3"  BackgroundColor="#C8DBEF" TextColor="#01426A" ConfigurationItem ="{Binding .}" Grid.Row="1" Text="Show" VerticalOptions="Center" CornerRadius="16" FontSize="10" BorderWidth="0" Clicked="Button_OnClicked_ShowItem2"/>
                                            <customRenders:MyButton x:Name="DownButtonFrame3"  BackgroundColor="#C8DBEF" TextColor="#01426A" ConfigurationItem ="{Binding .}" Grid.Row="0"  Text="Download"  CornerRadius="16" FontSize="10" HeightRequest="34" BorderWidth="0" Clicked="Button_OnClicked_DownItem2"/>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </StackLayout>
                                </AbsoluteLayout>

                            </AbsoluteLayout>
                        </Grid>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: First show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: Can Stackoverflow team open this Question please?

Answer (score 1):

You should add the `TapGestureRecognizer` on an Image and attach a Command to it, as given below:

```
<Grid>
    <Image Source="myImage.png">
        <Image.GestureRecognizers>
            <TapGestureRecognizer
                Command="{Binding ImageTapCommand}"
                CommandParameter="Id or ImageName or any Parameter goes here" />
        </Image.GestureRecognizers>
    </Image>    
    <Button Text="MyButton" IsVisible="{Binding ButtonVisibility, Mode=TwoWay}"  HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" />
</Grid>
```

In Your ViewModel or Model:

```
private bool _buttonVisibility;
public bool ButtonVisibility
{
    get { return _buttonVisibility; }
    set { _buttonVisibility = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ButtonVisibility)); }
}

private Command<string> _ImageTapCommand;
public Command<string> ImageTapCommand
{
    get
    {
        return _ImageTapCommand ?? (_ImageTapCommand = new Command<string>((str) => ImageTapCommandExecute(str)));
    }
}

void ImageTapCommandExecute(string str)
{
    //Here str is whatever you passed with CommandParameter.
    //When your Image is tapped, button gets visible
    ButtonVisibility = true;                
}
```

This is just a rough code I provided to you for what you want to achieve. May this help you.